# Update Statement Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have table called status which has data like this:

```
ID   Status  Number
1    S       1
1    p       2
1    S       3
1    C       4
2    S       5
2    R       6
```

I wanted to get rid of duplicates in this table so I added another column to this table called Flag and I set this to 1 for all the records. Now my table looks like this:

```
ID   Status  Number  Flag
1    S       1       Y
1    p       2       Y
1    S       3       Y
1    C       4       Y
2    S       5       Y
2    R       6       Y
```

I am writing an update query on this to update the flag column to N if it has duplicates and the update query is:

The Number column is identity in the table.

```
udate status
set flag = 'N'
where flag = 'Y' and Number in 
(select min(Number) from status
where id = 1
having count(*) >1)
```

So If do I this query it gives me data without duplicates

```
Select status from status
where flag = Y
```

But the update query doesn't work if i have 3 similar values for status. The update works only if i have 2 similar values for status.

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to get rid of duplicates on `id` or on `(id, status)`?

Comment: Are you trying to update all of the rows that have duplicates flag value to `N` or just the first one?

Comment: does it work if you remove the `flag = 'Y'` from your UPDATE's WHERE clause?

Comment: Quassnoi I am trying to get rid of deuplicates on Status. msarchet update all the rows

Comment: @Sam: are records with same `status` and different `id` considered duplicates? If you have `3` duplicates, do you want to flag them all or only the last `2`?

Comment: @Quassnoi No same status with different id are not considered as duplicates. If I have 3 duplicates I want to falg 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to flag duplicates only (leaving the first value untouched):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, status ORDER BY number) AS rn
        FROM    status
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     flag = CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

or this to flag all values having duplicates:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status) AS cnt
        FROM    status
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     flag = CASE cnt WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I try the above query : Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The COUNT function requires 1 argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()` to select the first row of a particular partition:

```
update  t
set     flag = case when rn = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
from    (
        select  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by status order by number) as rn
        ,       *
        from    @t
        ) t
```